# No man page for the cd command

Tags: linux, shell, command, built-in, ubuntu-15.10

Ubuntu Linux 15.10 - I just noticed that there is no man page for `cd`

This seems a bit strange.

I tried:

```
man cd
```

at the cmd line and I get back

```
No manual entry for cd
```

I was trying to find documentation on

```
cd -
```

which is super-handy for flipping between the last dir and the current dir

and `cd --`

which seems to be an alias for

```
cd ~
```

Am I missing something very obvious here, or should the man page be present?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`cd` is not a command, it's built into your shell. This is necessary because your current working directory is controlled by the `PWD` environment variable named after the `pwd` or "print working directory" command.

The environment variables of a parent process cannot be changed by a child process. So if your shell ran `/bin/cd` which changed `PWD` it would only affect `/bin/cd` and anything it ran. It would not change the shell's `PWD`.

Some systems, like OS X and CentOS, map the `cd` man page to `builtin` which lists all the shell built ins and lets you know you should look at your shell's man page.

You can check what shell you have with `echo $SHELL`, it's probably `bash`.

Comment: I don't get what your explanation about environment variables has to do with `cd` not being listed on `man`. May I request further explanation put more easily? :)

Comment: @SmartHumanism A `cd` program cannot change your directory, so it has to be built into the shell, so it's not a program. `man` is set up for programs, so `cd` doesn't get a man page. Even if we decided it should anyway, every shell has a slightly different `cd`. Which one gets `man cd`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 21):

`cd` is a builtin shell command.

```sh
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

You can open a help page for `cd` on Bash with

```sh
$ help cd
```

Which currently shows (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
$ help cd
cd: cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]
    Change the shell working directory.

    Change the current directory to DIR.  The default DIR is the value of the
    HOME shell variable.

    The variable CDPATH defines the search path for the directory containing
    DIR.  Alternative directory names in CDPATH are separated by a colon (:).
    A null directory name is the same as the current directory.  If DIR begins
    with a slash (/), then CDPATH is not used.

    If the directory is not found, and the shell option `cdable_vars' is set,
    the word is assumed to be  a variable name.  If that variable has a value,
    its value is used for DIR.

    Options:
        -L  force symbolic links to be followed: resolve symbolic links in
        DIR after processing instances of `..'
        -P  use the physical directory structure without following symbolic
        links: resolve symbolic links in DIR before processing instances
        of `..'
        -e  if the -P option is supplied, and the current working directory
        cannot be determined successfully, exit with a non-zero status
        -@  on systems that support it, present a file with extended attributes
            as a directory containing the file attributes

    The default is to follow symbolic links, as if `-L' were specified.
    `..' is processed by removing the immediately previous pathname component
    back to a slash or the beginning of DIR.

    Exit Status:
    Returns 0 if the directory is changed, and if $PWD is set successfully when
    -P is used; non-zero otherwise.
```

Unfortunately, it does not answer your questions. There *is* documentation that does, however.

You can get to it with

```sh
$ man builtins
```

It opens many pages of help with `less`, my default viewer. I can find the help for cd by pressing the `/` key, then typing `cd`, then `Enter`, and pressing `n` twice gets me to the third instance of the substring, and the help, which reads:

```
   cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]
          Change  the  current  directory to dir.  if dir is not supplied,
          the value of the HOME shell variable is the default.  Any  addi‐
          tional arguments following dir are ignored.  The variable CDPATH
          defines the search path for the directory containing  dir:  each
          directory  name  in  CDPATH  is  searched  for dir.  Alternative
          directory names in CDPATH are separated by a colon (:).  A  null
          directory  name  in CDPATH is the same as the current directory,
          i.e., ``.''.  If dir begins with a slash (/), then CDPATH is not
          used.  The  -P  option  causes  cd to use the physical directory
          structure by resolving symbolic links while traversing  dir  and
          before processing instances of .. in dir (see also the -P option
          to the set builtin command); the -L option forces symbolic links
          to  be followed by resolving the link after processing instances
          of .. in dir.  If .. appears in dir, it is processed by removing
          the  immediately previous pathname component from dir, back to a
          slash or the beginning of dir.  If the  -e  option  is  supplied
          with  -P,  and  the current working directory cannot be success‐
          fully determined after a successful directory  change,  cd  will
          return  an unsuccessful status.  On systems that support it, the
          -@ option presents the extended  attributes  associated  with  a
          file  as  a directory.  An argument of - is converted to $OLDPWD
          before the directory change is attempted.  If a non-empty direc‐
          tory  name  from  CDPATH is used, or if - is the first argument,
          and the directory change is successful, the absolute pathname of
          the  new  working  directory  is written to the standard output.
          The return value is  true  if  the  directory  was  successfully
          changed; false otherwise.
```

Look for the `-` argument about the seventh line from the end:

> An argument of `-` is converted to `$OLDPWD` before the directory change is attempted.

Note that there is no `--` argument - which seems to mean that it actually ignores it.

Answer (score -3):

relevant excerpt from the bash man page covering usage of `cd -`

```
       cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]
              Change the current directory to dir. 
              ...

              An argument of  -
              is  converted to $OLDPWD before the directory change is attempted.  If a non-
              empty directory name from CDPATH is used, or if - is the first argument,  and
              the  directory change is successful, the absolute pathname of the new working
              directory is written to the standard output.  The return value is true if the
              directory was successfully changed; false otherwise.
```

Comment: The question is about why the man page isn't there and where it is. Pasting in the section on `cd` isn't a good answer, and it only applies to that particular shell. Yes, I realize you asked the question.

Comment: it does help a bit with the part of the OP on documentation of the cd -  option, doesn't seem to mention cd -- though.. I wonder if it is actually an alias for cd ~?

Comment: `--` is a generic way to say "end of options", everything following will be a file or argument. It's handy to work with files that start with dashes. `cd --` is equivalent to `cd`. And, again, there is no "the cd command", it is built into your shell and the details depend on what shell your using. `zsh`, for example, behaves differently.

Comment: thanks for the additional clarification - I found this resource to be very helpful also - https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html