# How to delete site-package to remove WARNING for invalid distribution?

Tags: bash, terminal

I have the following WARNING on my terminal:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
```

Having read some other reviews, I know that if I delete the folder it will get rid of the warning. But I can't seem to find the folder. I am using a Mac and I've tried to look for it manually.

Any ideas how to locate the folder or just delete it via my terminal?

Comment: What command did you provide to produce the following output?

Answer (score 0):

The location of the folder is given in the error: `/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages`.

I would assume you did not see the directory because macOS hides root directories (and dotfiles) by default in Finder. Here is a [guide](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-access-your-macs-hidden-files) to show hidden files on macOS.

However, we can go to the directory and delete the directory in the Terminal.

First, you can go to the directory with

```bash
cd /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

Let us breakdown what this command does:

| classification | part of command | explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [built-in program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41147924/14111707) | `cd` | The Change Directory command. It takes one argument, a file(you could call it a directory, but technically everything in Unix is a file) you want to go to. |
| command line argument | `/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages` | This is the directory you are supplying to `cd` |

Second, you can remove the directory with

```bash
rm --recursive --force /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

Let us also break down what this command does:

| classification | part of command | explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| program | `rm` | The remove command removes files from your file system. It takes in the file(s) you want removed. |
| flag | `--recursive` | This flag tells `rm` to remove the contents of a directory provided. |
| flag | `--force` | This flag makes sure that `rm` does not prompt while we are removing the directory |
| command line argument | `/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages` | This is the directory `rm` is going to delete |

I highly suggest you read the [Manual pages](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/reading_unix_manual_pages) for <s>these two</s> this program. See `man rm`(`cd` does not have a Man page).

The shell is a very powerful tool once you master it. Here is a [tutorial](https://missing.csail.mit.edu/2020/course-shell/) that might be of use to you.

Answer (score -3):

If you can download Visual Studio Code, try to install the packages from the terminal there. Once the error pops up on the terminal in Visual Studio Code, press <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> on the path and it should take you to the actual folder. What you then want to do is delete the folders that start with `~`. You can then delete Visual Studio Code after if you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: While this is one method to find the folder, nothing needs to be installed to perform this task.

Comment: This is quite possibly the worst possible solution. OP just needs help finding the directory. There's no reason, nor is it remotely reasonable, to download a gigantic IDE to just get help browsing your file system. Most OSes already have built-ins GUIs to do that for you.